# Is there a way to create a react popup modal without using a third party package

Tags: reactjs

I tried using the technique below, but the modal does not blur out the rest of the content. At the same time, I would like to make it reusable and avoid manipulating the elements' z-index

```
return (
        <>
            <div className='dashboard-main-neworder' onClick={newOrder}>
                <img alt='New Order' src={addorder}></img>
                <span>New Order</span>
            </div>
            {selected && (
                <div className='neworder'>
                    <div className='neworder-title'>
                        <p>ORDER DETAILS</p>
                    </div>
```

Comment: By "blur out" are you referring to HTML's `blur` (as in, controls losing focus) or visually blurring (CSS' `filter: blur(2px);`)?

Comment: Have you looked at HTML's `<dialog>` element? It supports modal display and you can add a backdrop-blur effect with `dialog[open]::backdrop { filter: blur(2px); }`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out portals (https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html).
They provide a way to attach react nodes somewhere else in the dom tree (let's say next to you #app node so that your modal is always on top of your application, and you can then add a blur effect if that's what you want on your app below the modal.